# How to programmatically disable a Process Builder

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder

I have created an Apex Trigger to update a custom object, but a process that fires upon creating or editing the same object also fires. The result is a limit error. In my Trigger, I would like to write a piece of code that disables and then enables the Process Builder process. Does anyone know how I could go about this or have any other suggestions? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Boolean checkbox field on custom setting.Then update your Process Builders so that the very first entry criterion is the custom setting being true, and if it is not, stop.

Then from Apex you will be able to set the Custom Setting field to false whenever you need to stop the processes from executing.